# How to manipulate the label of an axis in JQplot?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jqplot

I'm not trying to modify the ticks label (that can be done through the `ticksOptions`), but the axis label.

I'm trying to do so because my axis label is overriding my ticks label - or maybe it's the opposite :)

I tried using the `labelOptions` property but couldn't move my label's position.

note: this label is defined through the `label:my_text` property.

Comment: You can modify the CSS directly: See this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/12784780/888177

Answer (score 0):

Below setting is for axes label:

```
axes: {
   xaxis: {
      labelOptions: {
         label: "name"
      }
   },
   yaxis: {
      labelOptions: {
         label: "name"
      }
   }
}
```

And below is for legend labels:

```
series: [
   {
      label: "label of serie one"
   }, {
      label: "label of serie two"
   }
]
```

Current documentation in the project site is missing many information as it is stated there already. Currently, the best thing to do is reading the documentation in the code (which is not very difficult).

Hope this helps.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply, but actually, as stated in the question, I already found the "labelOptions" property. The issue is that I can't find how to manage the position of the label. I found a workaround with manipulating the entire axis style, through css manipulating the jqplot-yaxis class.

Comment: Oh, sorry. There is "plugins/jqplot.canvasAxisLabelRenderer.js" for modifying the axis label (e.g. font family/size, rotation angle) but I could find an option that may help you. On the other hand, the result you get is a little weird, the only thing I can say is "do you use latest ver.?" Btw CSS solution is not a workaround, but a real solution. Overwriting the CSS files makes great flexibilty.

Comment: yes I'm using the latest version. Issue is really that the label I set can be overwritten by the Ticks labels, which makes them both unreadable. Css on jqplot-yaxis allows one to manipulate the global axis text, not only the axis label. Anyway I decided to set the label in the title, to display the wanted information.